# Sorting a html select box but ignoring the select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a dyamically created html select box that i need to sort alphabetically but ignore the placeholder/option that says Select...

I've tired the following from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895139/how-to-sort-fields-in-a-select-list-but-ignore-one-option/72576923?noredirect=1#comment128204869_72576923) but realised the select box doens't have an ID only a Name

any ideas?

```
<select style="width:250px" name="sortbyco">
    <option value="">Select2</option>
    <!--I would like to keep this at the top-->
    <option value="40934">Africa (CAF)</option>
    <option value="44624">Asia (AFC)</option>
    <option value="29521">Europe (UEFA)</option>
    <option value="43099">North &amp; Central America (CONCACAF)</option>
    <option value="38731">South America (CONMEBOL)</option>
    <option value="46617">Oceania (OFC)</option>
    <option value="40934">Africa (CAF2)</option>
</select>



$("#sortbyco").append($("#sortbyco option:gt(0)").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

Comment: instead of `#sortbyco` use a different css selector, `[name='sortbyco']`, or simply add `id='sortbyco'` to the `<select>` tag, if possible

Comment: How is this list being dynamically generated? Could you sort the options BEFORE you generate the select box?

Comment: unfortunaltey its from a plugin so we can't order it before it's created!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet without JQuery. The selector now has an id for easier use in a css selector. A copy of the options array without the empty option is sorted, and re-added to the selector.

```js
const selector = document.querySelector(`#sortbyco`);

// create an array of all options except the empty one
const opts = [...selector.querySelectorAll(`option:not([value='']`)];

// copy to a sorted array (note: use localeCompare to compare strings)
const sortedOpts = opts.sort( (a, b) => 
  a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent) );

// remove the old options from the selector
opts.forEach(opt => opt.remove());

// add the sorted options to the selector
sortedOpts.forEach( (opt, i) => selector.appendChild(opt) );
```

```html
<select style="width:250px" id="sortbyco">
    <option value="46617">Oceania (OFC)</option>
    <option value="43099">North &amp; Central America (CONCACAF)</option>
    <option value="40934">Africa (CAF)</option>
    <option value="44624">Asia (AFC)</option>
    <option value="29521">Europe (UEFA)</option>
    <option value="40934">Africa (CAF2)</option>
    <option value="38731">South America (CONMEBOL)</option>
    <option value="" selected>Select</option>
    <!-- ▲ will be at the top after sorting -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  var opts = $("#sortbyco > option:not([value=''])").detach();
  opts.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text() == $(b).text() ? 0 : $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? -1 : 1;
  });
  $("#sortbyco").append(opts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:250px" name="sortbyco" id="sortbyco">
  <option value="">Select2</option>
  <!--I would like to keep this at the top-->
  <option value="40934">Africa (CAF)</option>
  <option value="44624">Asia (AFC)</option>
  <option value="29521">Europe (UEFA)</option>
  <option value="43099">North &amp; Central America (CONCACAF)</option>
  <option value="38731">South America (CONMEBOL)</option>
  <option value="46617">Oceania (OFC)</option>
  <option value="40934">Africa (CAF2)</option>
</select>
```

This uses `.sort()` on the  Array of jQuery Objects.